# iOS WDA http://127.0.0.1:8100/inspector "error" : "unknown command"

Tags: xcode, appium, ios-targets

when I run http://127.0.0.1:8100/status, the status is normal.

```
{
  "value" : {
    "state" : "success",
    "os" : {
      "name" : "iOS",
      "version" : "13.3"
    },
    "ios" : {
      "simulatorVersion" : "13.3",
      "ip" : "192.168.3.21"
    },
    "build" : {
      "time" : "Dec 22 2020 14:54:08"
    }
  },
  "sessionId" : null,
  "status" : 0
}
```

however, when I run http://127.0.0.1:8100/inspector, I came across "unkown command" issue.

```
{
  "value" : {
    "error" : "unknown command",
    "message" : "Unhandled endpoint: \/inspector -- http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8100\/ with parameters {\n    wildcards =     (\n        inspector\n    );\n}"
  },
  "sessionId" : null,
  "status" : 6
}
```

where is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that
"This is expected. Because the built-in inspector module has been removed from the fork in favor of Appium Desktop's one."

REF: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/issues/367